# How to run a specific .tf file from multiple .tf files

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

i am a beginner in terraform . suppose we have a multiple terraform file for multiple services in a single directory and want the user to select which service he wants to deploy, only those services will be applied.

want the user to select which service he wants to deploy, only those services will be applied.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell. But, based on the question, the answer is no, all tf files which are in the same directory are read by terraform. What you are looking for are most likely modules.

Comment: One way to apply selected resources is via using the target option. `terraform apply -target="<resource>.<resource-name>"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.